# Why is this question closed as "not constructive"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reopen-closed

I recently discovered Twitter Bootstrap and went searching stack overflow for some help in understanding it.

I found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560693/twitter-bootstrap-any-tutorials

It's the most upvoted question tagged with twitter-bootstrap. Although there can be multiple answers, it's not really subject. And has obviously helped a lot of people judging by the views and upvotes. (13,000 views in 9 months!)

Why was this question closed? There are quite a few questions like it that aren't. I don't get it.

Comment: We're not a search machine.

Comment: `There are quite a few questions like it that aren't.` Please post the links, and watch them being closed and deleted in no time!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136648/should-lets-close-old-recommendation-questions

Comment: The question asked is "*Are there any tutorials for Twitter's Bootstrap?*". And the likely answer is - Yes, probably. Having people google links and add them as answers isn't very helpful.

Comment: 13K views in 9 months is nothing in the scheme of things.

Comment: @casperOne Nor do views=quality. Which of coursse *you* know, but... just sayin'!

Comment: @Andrew we need a meta post "what votes/views are not..." to list all the things.

Answer (score 7):

It was closed as Not Constructive on the grounds that it was a question that couldn't reasonably have a Correct answer at any particular time; there simply *isn't* a definitive tutorial that covers everything and that everyone would recommend for anyone getting started. There might be other questions in the same area that seek the same information, but that does not mean that those questions are OK either; they might just be undetected duplicates or other candidates for closure for non-constructivity.

Eventually, the information that is in that question should be migrated to the appropriate tag wiki (the one for [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) I'd guess) but as of the time of me writing this, that has not happened. The tag wikis are also largely not nearly visible enough when searching; in particular I've never seen one as the result of a google search (but that might reflect more on what I've searched for). But for now, be satisfied that you've found the information. ***That's Good!***

Comment: Tutorials never cover everything. If they did, they'd be incomprehensible to those starting out.

Comment: Can moderator move automatically a question to the appropriate wiki tag?